# Which type of schema.org should I use for goods prices table related to specific place?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I've got a few pages on the site describing prices for various products and services in different cities.

For example, on the city page of Paris there is a following table:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------+
| Ticket for the Eiffel Tower for an adult | 10 EUR |
+------------------------------------------+--------+
| Ticket for the Eiffel Tower for a child  | 5 EUR  |
+------------------------------------------+--------+
| Ice cream                                | 2 EUR  |
+------------------------------------------+--------+
|                 . . .                    | . . .  |
+------------------------------------------+--------+
| Taxi from the airport                    | 14 EUR |
+------------------------------------------+--------+
```

What is the best way to mark this data using schema.org? Should I use http://schema.org/City or more general http://schema.org/Thing type? Can I use http://schema.org/Product inside city type somehow? And I also wondering how to combine multiple rows in the table together. I'm totally confused and will appreciate any advice.

Comment: Are all of these actual prices (so you also specify the shop/provider?), or also estimated costs (e.g., the ice might as well cost 1.80 or 2.20 etc.)?

Comment: For now it's estimated costs, but in closest future there will be also actual prices with brand, manufacturer, etc.